# Last refresh time stamp of a BOXI report

Tags: sdk, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

what is the infostore method to retreive the Last Refresh Time of a report in Business objects XI R3

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.DocumentInstance you can get the last run time by asking the properties.

```
Properties docProps = documentInstance.getProperties();
docProps.getProperty(PropertiesType.LAST_REFRESH_DURATION, "0");
```

All of the details can be found in the <WEB APP Install>\AnalyticalReporting\viewers\cdz_adv\viewDocument.jsp